# What properties are returned by ModMenuHelper::getList()?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm having difficulty finding information on the properties you can access for menu items when building joomla menus. For instance, how do I tell if a menu item has other items below it? Can I use $item->tree? What exactly is stored in $item->tree?

I'm kind of new to Joomla development and I'm trying to build some custom functionality for our menus. But I feel like I don't know all the tools available to me to build it. Their documentation seems lacking in this respect.